# How to prevent output on shell using python

Tags: python-3.x, shell, networking, subprocess

I'm trying to pull/transfer a file from a cisco switch to a jump server(linux). The process is successful using the subprocess.call command however once executed it displays a 'password' prompt on the screen. 
I want to find a way so that I can hide this prompt from being displayed on the shell. Also when this prompt occurs I want to send a password so that the transfer is complete. In a way make the script interactive. I have mentioned a small part of my script below, Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(device_name, username=username, password=password)
client.exec_command('show version > bootflash:sh_ver.txt')
client.close()
cmd = <command to pull file from the switch to the local dir on jump server>  
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')    output = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, 
stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Are you sure the process is successful ? the password prompt indicates that the 'connect' might have failed. Also, what is the 'command to pull file ...' - you script closes to the connection to the switch before executing the retrieval command.

Comment: The scp file transfer process is successful when I submit the password at the prompt. I'm pulling the file from the switch when I'm on the dump server(all dump servers have access to the switch but request for LDAP credentials). The connection to the switch is closed as I do not need to be logged in at that time.
The command is :
scp username@switchname://Techsupport.txt  /uploads/filename